# Disable leading underscore removal in attrs auto-generated init method signature

Tags: python-attrs

`attr` [strips](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/init.html#private-attributes) leading underscore from attribute names for the generated `__init__` method . Is there a way to override that for a particular attribute, short of disabling auto-generated initialization method for the class entirely?

I'd like to use `attr` class to represent MongoDB documents, which in Python are dictionaries with the `_id` key to record the unique id. I was hoping to be able to have a `from_db(cls, doc)` class method that's little more than `return cls(**doc)`, but the presence of `_id` causes "TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument '_id'". Right now, I work around it by declaring `_id: attr.ib(init=False, default=None), and having:

```
@classmethod from_db(cls, doc):
    _id = doc["_id"]
    del(doc["_id"])
    obj = cls(**doc)
    obj._id = _id
    return obj
```

but that seems really klugey. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently not possible, sorry.

See:

- https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/issues/391
- https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/issues/619

Long-term you'll probably run into more complicated exceptions and then tools like cattrs make more sense.